# Nodejs http.createServer callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok, so this is what I have:

```
const http = require("http");

const Server = function(){
  this.context = {};
};

Server.prototype.callback = function(req, res){
  console.log(this.context);
};

Server.prototype.listen = function(...arguments){
  const server = http.createServer(this.callback);
  return server.listen(...arguments);
};

module.exports = Server;
```

It logs `context` as `undefined`, but when I call the function without `http.createServer` it works, why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the object to the callback.  When you pass `this.callback` as an argument, it only passes the callback and there is no attachment to the object.  So, when `http.createServer()` calls your callback, it calls the `callback()` method as a regular function and the object value of `this` is lost.

You can fix by changing this:

```
http.createServer(this.callback);
```

to this:

```
http.createServer(this.callback.bind(this));
```

This is a very common issue when passing methods as a callback.  Another alternative would be this:

```
http.createServer(() => this.callback());
```